# Solving differential equation of vector values function.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Through working on problems on the Frenet frame I have come across the following problem.
Prove that if $\kappa$ and $\tau$ are nonzero constants, then the curve is a (right) circular helix. There is a hint for this problem that says,

Start by solving for $N$. The only solutions of the differential equation $y^{''}+k^2y=0$ are $y=c_2\cos(kt)+ c_2\sin(kt) $.

Through some work I have obtained the following differential equation,

$${\bf N}^{\prime\prime}(s)+[\kappa^2+\tau^2]{\bf N}(s)=0$$

I have a couple questions. First, how do we use this hint to solve this differential equation? Second, once we have the solution how do we deduce that this is a right circular helix? My idea for the second question is to use the relation ${\bf T}^\prime=\kappa{\bf N}$ and then integrate but this to figure out what the curve is but this leaves me trying to figure out what ${\bf N}$ is. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general approach is good. The key is to write down all three components of the differential equation. If $\mathbf{N} = (N_1, N_2, N_3)$, then the (vector-valued) differential equation for $\mathbf{N}$ gives three (scalar) differential equations:
$$
    N''_i + (\kappa^2 + \tau^2) N_i = 0 \quad \text{for $i=1,2,3$.}
$$
You can solve these using the hint.

Next, you have to solve at all three components of the differential equation $\mathbf{T'}=\kappa \mathbf{N}$ in order to find $\mathbf{T}$. And finally, you integrate $\mathbf{T}$ to find the general form of the parametrization.

Comment: Following this approach, would we end up with a solution that looked like
$$N_1=c_1\cos((\kappa^2+\tau^2)t)+c_2\sin((\kappa^2+\tau^2)t)$$?

Comment: Almost.The constant in the (co)sine is $\sqrt{\kappa^2+\tau^2}$.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.